# Returning multiple values in python and appending them to unique columns to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

**Background:**

I have a function that gets a bunch of attributes from a database. Here is the function:

```
def getData(key, full_name, address, city, state, zipcode):
    try:
        url = 'https://personator.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/ContactVerify/doContactVerify'
        payload={
                'TransmissionReference': "test", # used by you to keep track of reference
                'Actions': 'Check',
                'Columns': 'Gender','DateOfBirth','DateOfDeath','EthnicCode','EthnicGroup','Education','PoliticalParty','MaritalStatus','HouseholdSize','ChildrenAgeRange','PresenceOfChildren','PresenceOfSenior','LengthOfResidence','OwnRent','CreditCardUser','Occupation','HouseholdIncome',
                'CustomerID': key,# key
                'Records': [{'FullName': str(full_name), 'AddressLine1': str(address), 'City': str(city), 'State': str(state), 'PostalCode': str(zipcode)}]
                }
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Accept':'application/json', 'Host':'personator.melissadata.net','Expect': '100-continue', 'Connection':'Keep-Alive'}
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        dom = json.loads(r.text)

        Gender = dom['Records'][0]['Gender']
        DateOfBirth = dom['Records'][0]['DateOfBirth']
        DateOfDeath = dom['Records'][0]['DateOfDeath']
        EthnicCode = dom['Records'][0]['EthnicCode']
        EthnicGroup = dom['Records'][0]['EthnicGroup']
        Education = dom['Records'][0]['Education']
        PoliticalParty = dom['Records'][0]['PoliticalParty']
        MaritalStatus = dom['Records'][0]['MaritalStatus']
        HouseholdSize = dom['Records'][0]['HouseholdSize']
        ChildrenAgeRange = dom['Records'][0]['ChildrenAgeRange']
        PresenceOfChildren = dom['Records'][0]['PresenceOfChildren']
        PresenceOfSenior = dom['Records'][0]['PresenceOfSenior']
        LengthOfResidence = dom['Records'][0]['LengthOfResidence']
        OwnRent = dom['Records'][0]['OwnRent']
        CreditCardUser = dom['Records'][0]['CreditCardUser']
        Occupation = dom['Records'][0]['Occupation']
        HouseholdIncome = dom['Records'][0]['HouseholdIncome']

        return Gender
    except:
        return None
```

To make a 'Gender' column I wrap the function into a lambda as so

```
df['Gender'] = df.apply(lambda row: getData(key, row['Full Name'], row['Address'], row['City'], row['State'], row['Zipcode']))
```

**Objective:**
I want to do this process simultaneously for all the other attributes you see below Gender, how can I do this in Python.

Comment: Does the database record contain more attributes that the ones you want to obtain? Seems like you have the columns that you want in the payload, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a dictionary, then expand a series of dictionary objects:

```
fields = ['Gender', 'DateOfBirth', etc.]

def getData(key, full_name, address, city, state, zipcode):
    try:
        # your code as before
        dom = json.loads(r.text)
        return {k: dom['Records'][0][k] for k in fields}
    # modify below: good practice to specify exactly which error(s) to catch
    except:
        return {}
```

Then expand your series of dictionaries:

```
dcts = df.apply(lambda row: getData(key, row['Full Name'], row['Address'], row['City'],
                                    row['State'], row['Zipcode']), axis=1)

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(dcts.tolist()))
```

As per @spaniard's comment, if you want *all available* fields, you can simply use:

```
return json.loads(r.text)['Records'][0]
```

Comment: Probably he can just return `dom['Records'][0]` in `getData()` and then use `**getData(...)`.

Comment: @spaniard, Good point, I'm just wary of `fields` being a subset of all available fields.

Comment: yes, I know. I mentioned it because it seems that the `fields` he wants, it the same that he ask for in `payload['Columns']`

Comment: @spaniard If you're method is faster please provide an answer :)

Comment: jpp solution is good, you should accept it @Snorrlaxxx. If he wants, he can edit it with my comment, but a new answer does not make sense since it will be 99% the same. I don't think there is a performance difference, at least noticeable.